# Split View based application template in Xcode

Tags: ios, ipad

I am confused...

I just created a new test app using the Split View based application template that comes with Xcode 4.  According to the docs for UISplitViewController:

After creating and initializing an instance of this class, you must assign two view controllers to the viewControllers property.

However, in this code generated from the template there is nothing that sets this viewControllers property.  How is this working?  There is nothing in the .xib files that I can see which would account for this.

Where does this property get set?  I'm completely missing something here!

Thanks,

-Eric

Answer (score 0):

The view controllers are indeed set within IB.  Expand the hierarchy of objects in the IB dock and you'll see IB objects for two view controllers labeled Root View Controller and Detail View Controller.  If you select and examine these two objects using the IB identity inspector, you'll notice their class is set to specific class implementations found in that project.

Something else that might be helpful to look at: Create another project using the window based application template.  Add a split view to its MainWindow.xib and compare it in IB with the split view template.  In the window based template, you'l notice that the controllers found underneath the navigation controller consist of a generic uitableview controller and a uiview controller.  In the split view template these controllers map to specific implementations of UITableViewController (RootViewController) and UIVewController (DetailViewController)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  But the direct children of the Split View Controller are the "Navigation Controller" and the "Detail View Controller".  The "Root View Controller" is a descendant of the "Navigation Controller".  I guess I'm wondering what the rules are and how to find such rules.  I've seen nothing in the docs that describe this interaction between Split View Controllers and how things are set up in IB.

Comment: @Eric Perhaps this can help fill in the blanks: [SplitView Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial)